# Is the Iron Kingdoms entry adventure intentionally easy?

Tags: iron-kingdoms

So I just tried Iron Kingdoms, using the "quick start rules" and [the first adventure from their website](http://files.privateerpress.com/ironkingdoms/documents/adventures/IKRPG_Scenario_Fools_Rush_In.pdf).

I'm pretty sure I followed the rules correctly,  (though we didn't use grids, minis, or tape measures)... However as the GM, I did not attack the players at all.  In each combat, all the enemies died before they had a chance to make a move themselves.

Are there any obvious rules that I might have been doing wrong, or did they just get lucky with their initiative order, double grenades, and pow 14 slug gun?

The adventure was ["Fools Rush In"](http://files.privateerpress.com/ironkingdoms/documents/adventures/IKRPG_Scenario_Fools_Rush_In.pdf).

Comment: Considering that combat in IKRPG requires precise measurements to determine ranges, I'm curious how you managed it without models, tape measures, or a map (a grid would be bad - then people can cheat and better estimate ranges).

Comment: I wouldn't say precise measurements.  an inch is 6 feet.  The rules say you can use inches or the 6 feet. I once played a game with a measuring tape, and I'm never doing that again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and No. It was created to be an introductory adventure, and is meant more to introduce the world and system in an easy way. However, as the name suggests, it should provide a challenge for people who rush in and don't think - but, like the war game, the rules of this game rarely favor the hesitant. The problem is, it's a system with the ability to create some wildly different characters, so what might be a challenge for some characters is a cakewalk for others.

I personally feel that the adventure was too easy, but save for a few old school adventures, I tend to feel most published adventures are a bit easy, because they can't gauge strengths or weaknesses of PC characters.

Comment: Thanks.  Oddly, I used the pregens from the document, but only had 3 players.  Milo and the girl with the steam jack.  The third player made his own character who was much weaker than the pregens.

Answer (score 0):

As an introductory adventure, it wouldn't make sense for it to be overly difficult. That being said, as a player I found it to be exceptionally easy and very short. It leaves off in an strange place which didn't at all feel like the natural conclusion to the adventure. Since we all felt a little hard-done-by, our poor GM had to ad-lib the rest of the session.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but instead relates your own experiences, which would be better done as a comment.